# how to use react.js with tailwind.css

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to make a project with react.js and style it using tailwind.css, is that possible? and how

Hopefully the merging between react.js and styling tailwind.css can be done in one pack

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Answer (score 1):

There is official guide for most used frameworks, including react
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/framework-guides

Answer (score 1):

```
npx create-react-app (project name)

cd (project name)
```

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

then configure you template paths by adding the paths to all your template files in the tailwind.config.js

docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Tailwind with React and I suggest the following [guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app),
So you can setup the whole think step by step!